# SQL sum statement works weirdly

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use the sum statement in mysql but with no luck . Below is my query , I just want the qty field in the production order to get added up when the sales order number field and item matches ,the below query returns only one row adding up all the production order qty issued so far . I do have around 2000 sales orders and 3500 productions orders were issued pertaining to the sales order .

Any help would really be a life saver .

```
select 
 `tabSales Order`.`name` as "Sales Order:Link/Sales Order:120",
`tabSales Order`.`customer` as "Customer:Link/Customer:120",
 `tabSales Order Item`.item_code as "Item:Link/Item:120",
`tabSales Order Item`.item_name as "Des:Link/Item:120",
`tabSales Order Item`.qty as "Qty:Float:100",
 `tabSales Order Item`.delivered_qty as "Delivered Qty:Float:100",
 (`tabSales Order Item`.qty - ifnull(`tabSales Order Item`.delivered_qty, 0)) as "Qty to Deliver:Float:140",
`tabSales Order Item`.date as "Sch date:Date:100",
`tabItem`.thumbnail as "Cut wt:Data:60",
`tabProduct master`.grade as "Grade:Data:100",
`tabProduct master`.dieno as "Die no:Data:100",
`tabProduct master`.hammer as "Hammer:Data:50",
`tabProduct master`.rm_idl_cs as "Idl sec:Data:60",
`tabProduct master`.rm_alt_cs as "Alt sec:Data:60",
SUM(CASE WHEN `tabSales Order`.`name` = `tabProduction Order`.`sales_order` and `tabSales Order Item`.`item_code` = `tabProduction Order`.`production_item`
         THEN `tabProduction Order`.`qty`
    END) as "Issued:Int:80"

from
 `tabSales Order` 
LEFT JOIN `tabSales Order Item` ON ( `tabSales Order Item`.`parent` = `tabSales Order`.`name`
 and `tabSales Order`.docstatus = 1 and `tabSales Order`.status not in ("Stopped", "Closed") and ifnull(`tabSales Order Item`.delivered_qty,0) < ifnull(`tabSales Order Item`.qty,0))
LEFT JOIN `tabItem` ON `tabItem`.`item_code` = `tabSales Order Item`.`item_code`
LEFT JOIN `tabProduct master` ON `tabProduct master`.`part_no` = `tabSales Order Item`.`item_code`
LEFT JOIN `tabProduction Order` ON (`tabSales Order Item`.`item_code` = `tabProduction Order`.`production_item` and `tabSales Order`.`name` = `tabProduction Order`.`sales_order`)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is your group by statement?

Comment: Ouch, you are filtering on the left hand side tables of left joins within the `on` clause, that's a no go. Such filters should be in the where clause.

Comment: Your whole query does not make any sense to me. Pls provide sample data and expected output based on the sample data. At the moment I simply do not understand what you are after.

Comment: @CherifOdoo . Thanks a ton for the help . The group by statement solved my issue . Now I want to subtract the sum column from another column , how do I do that ?

Comment: @Shadow . Thanks a bunch sir , The group by statement solved my issue . Now I want to subtract the sum column from another column , how do I do that ?

Comment: Guys , I'm struck with one thing , adding this in the where clause shows an error .                                                                                             
 where
 (`tabSales Order Item`.qty - SUM(CASE WHEN `tabSales Order`.`name` = `tabProduction Order`.`sales_order` and `tabSales Order Item`.`item_code` = `tabProduction Order`.`production_item`
         THEN `tabProduction Order`.`qty`
    END)) > 0                                                                                                    I donot want those rows with the above column which is equal to zero

Comment: If you have a new question, then post it as a new question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you query return only one row it's because you are using aggregate function without group by statement.

if you want to put a condition based on aggregate function you should use 
`having` after `group by`

```
group by  col1, col2,..
having sum(col1) > 1
```